# Bootstrap Angular 2+ app on specific DOM element inside another framework

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, web-component, stenciljs, stencil-component

I'm trying to bootstrap an Angular 2+ app (6 to be precise) inside a specific DOM node. I want to do this inside a web component `my-component` (written with [StencilJS](https://stenciljs.com/)).

Ideally I could bootstrap from the root element of my web component with a selector or the HTMLElement.

The problem however is that Angular is instantianted "globally" on the page and therefore tries to interpret all tags as Angular components - not just the ones found inside my own web component:
[image]

I've tried 3 different approaches found on the web. However many of them still use the `.bootstrap` method which is no longer available in newer Angular versions. Others just instantiate components in a certain node but not the whole app.

`NgDoBootstrap` seemed to be a quite promising way but it also leads to Angular parsing all components found on the page.

I've created a repo to investigate the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

https://github.com/bitflower/ng-stencil

Comment: Would bundling your Angular app component as a Web Component (via Angular Elements) do the job? https://angular.io/guide/elements

Comment: Was thinking about the same sime minutes ago. Sure would work. Not sure though if the component I want to use is "simple" enough. It's the Angular Gridster 2.